# is there a way to only 'apt upgrade' security packages, not everything?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, security, upgrade

I'm used to going through and upgrading packages regularly on my servers.
As they are usually stable I don't have the time to troubleshoot a conflicting upgrade. I do want to keep them fully patched with security updates.

Is there a way to specify apt or apt-get to apply security updates only?

> 50 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
>
> 19 standard security updates